# Creating a Required Comment Hook for Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-hooks

Has anyone implemented a hook that requires developers to input x chars before successful submission?  I've looked up hooks but don't really understand how to implement this one for Subversion using Tortoise **specifically for a Windows Environment**.

Answer (score 4):

Simply right-click the top level of your Repository.  In the context-menu select TortoiseSVN, then Properties, to see this dialog:

[image]

Click the New button near the bottom right, and select Log Sizes.  Enter the number of characters you want to require for Commit and Lock (10 in example below).

[image]

Do a Commit from the top Level directory you just modified.  Now your repository requires all users to Comment before Committing changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://www.stillnetstudios.com/require-subversion-comments-minimum/) which was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247888/how-to-require-commit-messages-in-visualsvn-server)

Note that using client side commit requirements can work as well if you have developers you trust.

EDIT:

Then try this?
http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-05/0594.shtml
http://blog.tfanshteyn.com/2007/11/subversion-pre-commit-hooks.html

Comment: hehe, trust developers to add a rule to enforce them to submit with comments!  yea I wish the world was that simple and people were that dedicated and professional.  :)

Comment: that is a perl script.  I'm using Tortoise SVN on a windows Vista environment locally and Windows Server 2007 on our dev server.

Comment: I started reverting people's changes when they had no comments.  That went a long way to letting them know I was serious.  Sometimes comments are not necessary, sometimes a word or two is sufficient, but most times more is needed.

Comment: it's nice when you have that power, but most don't.

Comment: SO you have the authority to put on a server side script, but not revert?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JIRA together with Subversion, then use the [Commit Policy](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/1213415) add-on.

It can verify the number of characters in the commit messge with the condition named [Commit message must match a pattern](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-commit-policy-plugin/documentation/#message-pattern-condition). Even better you can use a regex like this to count only the non-whitespace characters:

```
(?:\S|\S\s*){10,}
```

The add-on allows keeping all these rules in a central place (JIRA) and it offers several other conditions to check the committer person, the committed files and so on.

*Disclaimer: this is a commercial add-on, and I'm a developer working on it.*