# SVN repository configuration

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, configuration-management

Is there any way to configure an SVN server such that it does not accept commits if a descriptive message related to changes are not entered or filled in?

PS: I use TortoiseSVN as the client and [svnserve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion#Features), version 1.4.2 (r22196) as the server (available default with the distribution).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to require commit messages in VisualSVN server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247888/how-to-require-commit-messages-in-visualsvn-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll want to look at pre-commit hooks. This SO question might help you:

[How to require commit messages in VisualSVN server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247888/how-to-require-commit-messages-in-visualsvn-server)

Comment: For quick readers like me, add executable permissions to "pre-commit" with out any extensions to it.

Answer (score 3):

Either use a pre-commit hook script (works with all svn clients since the check is done on the server), or set the tsvn:logminsize property (works only with TortoiseSVN).

Comment: Stefan rulez :)
Your next problem will be : How to avoid users to enter only spaces/not useful commit messages...